# Hotel Program - Add a customer

Tags: java, function, netbeans

Below I have created a hotel program that allows customers to stay in rooms. I have recently been able to create a function that views all current rooms of my program, however I am having trouble writing the correct code to **add a customer** inside the `addCustomer()` function. Here's my current code:

```
package hotelprogram;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class HotelProgram {

// global variables 

static String[] hotel = new String[7];

private static void initialise(String hotelRef[]) {

    for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
        hotelRef[x] = "e";
        System.out.println("initilise");
    }
}

private static void viewALL() {

    // Views all current rooms

    for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
        if (!hotel[x].equals("e")) {
            System.out.println("Room " + x + " occupied by " + hotel[x]);
        }else{
            System.out.println("Room" + x + " is Empty");
        }
    }
}

private static void addCustomer()
{
    // Add a customer

    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

    int roomNumfc;
    int roomNamefc;

    for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
    {
        System.out.println("Select room number to add a customer: ");
        roomNumfc = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("New customer to add: ");
        roomNamefc = sc.nextInt();

    }


}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String roomName;
    int roomNum = 0;
    char selectChoice;

    for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
        hotel[x] = "";
        initialise(hotel);
    }

    while (roomNum < 6) {
        // Displays current rooms

        for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++) {

            // displays an empty room

            if (hotel[x].equals("e")) {
                System.out.println("Room" + x + " is Empty");
            }
        }
        // Enter a room prompt

        System.out.println("Enter a room number from (0-5) or higher to stop (10 to display menu): ");
        roomNum = input.nextInt();

        if (roomNum == 10) {

            // menu if roomNum = 10

            System.out.println("Make a selection: ");
            System.out.println("A. Add a customer to room");
            System.out.println("V. View all rooms");
            selectChoice = input.next().charAt(0);

            switch (selectChoice) {
            case 'A':
                addCustomer();
                break;
            case 'V':
                viewALL();
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Bad input, exiting program...");
                break;
            }
            break;
        }
        // Name current room promt

        System.out.println("Please name this room: " + roomNum + " :");
        roomName = input.next();
        hotel[roomNum] = roomName;

        // Room displayed
        for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
            if (!hotel[x].equals("e")) {
                System.out.println("Room " + x + " occupied by " + hotel[x]);
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not too sure how to access the global array that is used, could really use some help on  this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Dont put your program logic other than gathering input (at the most) in your main. Create an instance of your class and call methods on that instance:

```
public static void main(String... args){
    HotelProgram hotel = new HotelProgram();
    //...gather input
    //while input != 10
        //get room num
        //get room name
        hotel.addCustomer(num, name);
        hotel.printRooms();

}
```

By doing it that way you are following the Object Oriented design and avoiding the nasty use of global arrays/variables.

Here is your code modified to eliminate globals and be more OO friendly:

```
public class HotelProgram {
    private String[] rooms = new String[7];

    public HotelProgram(){
        initialise();
    }

    private void initialise() {
        for (int x = 0; x < rooms.length; x++) {
            rooms[x] = "e";
        }
        System.out.println("initilise is complete.");
    }

    public void printRooms() {
        for (int i = 0; i < rooms.length; i++){
            if(rooms[i].equals("e")){
                System.out.println("Room(" + (i+1) + ") is Empty.");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Room(" + (i+1) + ") is occupied by " + rooms[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    public void addCustomer(Scanner sc){
        int roomNum = 0;
        while(roomNum-1 < 0 || roomNum-1 > rooms.length-1){
            System.out.println("Enter a room number from (1-" + (rooms.length) + "):");
            roomNum = sc.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("Please provide the customer name for room " + (roomNum) + " :");
        sc.nextLine();
        String customer = sc.nextLine();
        rooms[roomNum-1] = customer;
    }

    public void printMenu(){
         System.out.println("\nMake a selection: ");
         System.out.println("A. Add a customer to room");
         System.out.println("V. View all rooms");
         System.out.println("M. Print this menu.");
         System.out.println("E. Exit\n");
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HotelProgram hotel = new HotelProgram();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        hotel.printMenu();

        String selection = "";
        while(true){
            selection = sc.nextLine();
            switch(selection){
                 case "E":
                    System.out.println("Thanks for visiting. Have a good day!");
                    System.exit(0);
                case "A":
                    hotel.addCustomer(sc);
                    break;
                case "V":
                    hotel.printRooms();
                    break;
                case "M":
                    hotel.printMenu();
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Bad input (" + selection + "), Try Again...");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not good OO design. I highly recommend you to change your program logic. Also, better access your variables through getter and setter methods and avoid using static variables. However, if you want to access your static array in main(), you should create an instance of your class

```
HotelProgram myhotel = new HotelProgram();
myhotel.hotel[i]=.... // i can be any of the allowed array indices.
```